# Docker use journald to collect log but can not remove old log file

Tags: docker, systemd-journald

I'm using `journald` to collect docker's file.

`Journald` conf:

```
[Journal]
Storage=auto
ForwardToSyslog=no
ForwardToWall=no
SystemMaxUse=100G
```

So I want to delete files larger than 100g. In fact, `journald` had deleted those files.

But I found the Disk space does not decrease, I use `lsof | grep delete` found those files handle were occupied by `dockerd` process.

```
dockerd    1524          root   25r      REG             253,17 125829120     278262 /data/opt/log/journal/963c2c41b08343f7b063dddac6b2e486/system@b9bd5cdeae2c416e92364e84cc3c09ec-00000000000153a
e-00055f2b2598f1f6.journal (deleted)
```

Because this is an production service, I can't restart docker.Is there any way to solve this problem?